# Nginx as a reverse proxy on IIS

Tags: nginx, iis, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy on iis.

It's okay to navigate to company.com.
But, company.com/market/product does not work.

Here is my conf;

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Expires 0;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

IIS at inetpub\wwwroot\company
Nginx looks for inetpub\wwwroot\company

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer;

```
location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```